# Rotated tiling background

Tags: website-design, background, tiles

How do I rotate the this image by 30 degrees but still have it be tileable?

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bAnk.png

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to create a pattern or tiles from rotated elements](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17132/8708)

Comment: explain: Do you have one image and or Static images(they will not be changing) or dynamic image...If dynamic then that means not texture.

Comment: I assume you want images to inside this image to tile, like by using css...or do you want the whole image as you said.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to say "you can't", but apparently it is possible:

http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/gimp/rotate_tileable_patterns

I'd rather not do all of that and come up with something else.

Comment: cool link useful...

Comment: Hi Steve! Do you think you could add some info from the link to your answer? Links can disappear, so it's better to have the instructions in here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Illustrator Pattern Maker.

Here is the demonstration of what I made quickly, I could have adjusted it but I guess it gets the point across:

[image]

You can see the detailed [instructions in this Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZYv5Ugv0SA).

This is why it's important to know what other programs can do. For example, there are things that only Corel draw can do which Photoshop and illustrator can't, even though they look very basic.