# How can I make this vector diagonal stripe texture seamless with Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture, tiles

I created a diagonal stripe image in Photoshop, just dragging the lines an "equal" distance from each other for a blueprint website design. I knew it would be much more complicated to recreate this diagonal texture in a seamless manner:

[image]

Perhaps there are tools to do this easily in Illustrator, but I'm limited to PS CS5.

**How can I achieve a seamless stripe texture at the angle shown here in Photoshop?**

Comment: It's a rather annoying thing to do. Here's another question that might help: [How to create a pattern or tiles from rotated elements](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17132/8708)

Comment: in the specific case of a stripe the transform is easier to do by eye tough.